# How do I find the Mammoth Tusk Powder for the "Repairing the Phial" quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have been to Stonehill Bluff several times now, and the Mammoth Tusk Powder is never there, is there anything else I can do to complete the 'Repairing the Phial' quest?

Comment: I am not trying to make my own powdered mammoths tusk...I need the special ingredient mammoth tusk powder (two different things) to finish the quest. I am told its only found at the Stonehill Bluff, but each time I go to the Bluff it is not there..

Comment: wups, my bad.  sorry

Answer (score 0):

If you are on the PC, you can use the console to add the quest item into your inventory via:

> player.additem 2c25e 1

Comment: Yeah but thats cheating ;)